# Could not set the List property. Invalid property value

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm getting this error and I don't know the reason.
I have the following piece of code:

```
Private Sub repereche_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("BD_IR")
Dim Rand As Long, Rand2 As Long
Dim prestrangere As Long
Dim prestrangere2 As Long
Dim bila As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("BD_AR")
prestrangere = 0
prestrangere2 = 0
bila = 10
Rand = 3
Rand2 = 3

Do While ws.Cells(Rand, 3).Value <> "" And Rand < 65000
    If Me.repereche.Value = Mid(ws.Cells(Rand, 3), 4, 10) Then
        Do While ws2.Cells(Rand2, 3).Value <> "" And Rand2 < 65000
            If Me.repereche.Value = Mid(ws2.Cells(Rand2, 3), 4, 10) Then
                If ws.Cells(Rand, 7) <> "" Then
                prestrangere = (((ws2.Cells(Rand2, 7) - 400) * 10) - ((ws.Cells(Rand, 6) - 400) * 10) - (bila * 1.414 * 2)) - 10
                prestrangere2 = (((ws2.Cells(Rand2, 6) - 400) * 10) - ((ws.Cells(Rand, 7) - 400) * 10) - (bila * 1.414 * 2)) - 10
                Else
                prestrangere = (((ws2.Cells(Rand2, 6) - 400) * 10) - ((ws.Cells(Rand, 6) - 400) * 10) - (bila * 1.414 * 2)) - 10
                End If
                gksluri.AddItem ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value 'comanda IR
                gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(Rand, 5) 'inel IR
                gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(Rand, 6) 'GKSL IR
                gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 3) = ws.Cells(Rand, 7) 'GKSL 2 IR
                gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 4) = ws2.Cells(Rand2, 4) 'comanda AR
                gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 5) = ws2.Cells(Rand2, 5) 'inel AR
                gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 6) = ws2.Cells(Rand2, 6) 'GKSL AR
                gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 7) = ws2.Cells(Rand2, 7) 'GKSL 2 AR
                gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 8) = bila
                gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 9) = prestrangere
                gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 10) = "test" 'HERE IS THE ERROR
            End If
        Rand2 = Rand2 + 1
        Loop
    End If
Rand2 = 3
Rand = Rand + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

gksluri is a Listbox. The Listbox has 11 columns set at the ColumnCount property. If I remove the line

```
gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 10) = "test"
```

it works ok. What am I doing wrong? Where could the problem be? I couldn't find anything.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `.List` is a 0 based array, so renumber 0..9 rather than 1..10

Comment: It's numbered 0-10 not 0-9 but for the first item I used Listbox.Value instead of .List

Comment: Something like gksluri.List(gksluri.ListCount - 1, 0) = ws.Cells(Rand, 4) won't work. How can I add values in the 11th column if List works only with 10 values?

Comment: You can't with an unbound list, you must either bind it or merge some of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an unbound data source, there is a 10-column limit (0 to 9).

From: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080556371.aspx